# Inheritance in JS, inheriting properties and values

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I am a beginner and can't understand how the prototypes and inheritance works in JavaScript. I am basing on the code here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance 
and I can't figure out how to inherit properties values, I can only get "methods". I think that maybe the more appropriate question is how to initiate fields of parent class when invoking a child object?

In accordance with the mentioned site, I wrote something like this:

```
    function Person(name, surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;     
    } 
function Student(index) {
    this.index = index;
    Person.call(this);
}

Student.prototype = new Osoba ();//I tried to insert values here in the constructor, it doesn't work
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;

var x = new Student ('89890');//tried to insert additional values here in the constructor, it also doesn't work
```

Is there a way to create a student and give him also a name and surname?

I am a total noobie so please explain like you would explain to a 5 year old. PS. I have to do this in JS so please don't recommend different ways, it won't help me, thanks :)

Comment: Maybe the following answer can help you, there is also a pattern that deals with constructor parameters but you can use that in any function chain: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach would be to have your child constructor repeat required parameters.

```
function Student(index, name, surname) {
    this.index = index;
    Person.call(this, name, surname);
}

var s = new Student ('89890', 'Jan', 'Kowalski');
```

Btw. this

```
Student.prototype = new Osoba ();
```

is certainly a typo, instead have

```
Student.prototype = new Person();
```

and you really don't need parameters here. The prototype will be initialized with `undefined` in property values and this is perfectly legal.

Comment: No, [it's not `new Person`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here)!

Comment: @Bergi: I don't quite get this comment, even following the link. Can you elaborate? Taken "as is", this comment is wrong.

Comment: I'm saying that `Student.prototype = new Person();` is wrong and should be `Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);`

Comment: @Bergi: agree. The confusion is your `not new Person` while you meant `not new Person()`

Comment: Yeah, the parenthesis can simply be omitted, I focused on the `new` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can change `Student` constructor to this one:

```
function Student(index, name, surname) {
    this.index = index;
    Person.call(this, name, surname);
}
```

[`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) takes optional parameters so you can invoke `Person` with additional arguments to set name and surname own properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inherit = function(C, P) {
      var F = function(){}; // i created this "proxy" to isolate the Parent constructor
      F.prototype = P.prototype;
      C.prototype = new F();
};

var Person = function(name, surname) {
       this.name = name || '';
       this.surname = surname || '';

       this.getName = function () {
         return this.name;
       }

      this.getSurname = function () {
         return this.surname;
      }
};


var Student = function(index, name, surname) {
  this.index = index;
  Person.call(this, name, surname);
};

inherit(Student, Person);

var student = new Student(0, 'Rodrigo', 'Fonseca');
alert(student.getName());
alert(student.getSurname());
```